# python ctypes how to map PTSTR

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

[There is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680355%28VS.85%29.aspx) WINAPI call definition:

```
DWORD MapFileAndCheckSum(
  _In_   PTSTR Filename,
  _Out_  PDWORD HeaderSum,
  _Out_  PDWORD CheckSum
);
```

How to pass PTSTR param for the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just:

```
filename = ctypes.c_char_p('something')  
filename = ctypes.c_wchar_p('something') # for unicode
```

Edit: answer was based on the definition of PWSTR, PSTR, and PTSTR on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751) and the [ctypes docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

And as suggested in the comments you should use restype/argtypes, especially if you are trying to be explicit, something like:

```
# define func
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(imagehlp)
mapfileandchecksuma = dll.MapFileAndCheckSumA
mapfileandchecksuma.restype = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD
mapfileandchecksuma.argtypes = [c_char_p,
                                POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
                                POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD)]

# call func
filename = 'ntkr128g.exe'
headersum  = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
checksum = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()    
if mapfileandchecksuma(filename,
                       byref(headersum),
                       byref(checksum)) == 0:
    print headersum.value, checksum.value
```

Comment: Seems like this does the trick. Can you explain it a bit to ensure that this call won't end up with segfault one day?

Comment: Updated with refs and suggestions by @eryksun.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the reference, the whole call to get checksum of PE binary turned up to be this:

```
filename = "ntkr128g.exe"
PTSTR = ctypes.c_char_p
headersum  = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
checksum = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
ctypes.windll.imagehlp.MapFileAndCheckSumA(
    PTSTR(filename), ctypes.byref(headersum), ctypes.byref(checksum))
print('head: 0x%08X, real: 0x%08X' % (headersum.value, checksum.value))
```

Comment: There's no need for `c_char_p`. ctypes passes a Python string as a pointer. Using `c_char_p` (or better, setting it in `argtypes`) will convert `unicode` to a temporary byte string for you, but only in Python 2. There are no implicit conversions between text and bytes in Python 3.

Comment: @eryksun, the most hard thing is to realize that the PTSTR is yet another alias to `c_char_p`. Passing Python string directly to ctypes smells like something wrong to me and in a few months I won't be sure about this code again, so better leave it xplicit.

Comment: If you read the docs/tutorial you'll find many examples of passing strings and small integers (i.e. C `int`) directly. ctypes was designed to make these cases easy. The bad practice is not setting `argtypes`. Another bad practice is using `cdll` and `windll` in a library, since it leads to conflicts with other libraries. Instead use `CDLL` and `WinDLL`.

Comment: @eryksun, I don't get how can `cddl` and `windll` conflict with other libraries?

Comment: `cdll` and `windll` cache loaded libraries, which in turn cache function pointers. I've come across cases, especially with common Windows DLLs, in which libraries set conflicting `argtypes`. It's simple to just use `dll = ctypes.WinDLL(dllpath)` instead. Or create a private loader, e.g. `windll = ctypes.LibraryLoader(ctypes.WinDLL)`.

Comment: @eryksun, so the `WinDLL` is only needed if you use `argtypes`. In this case `windll` will set `argtypes` globally and may override `argtypes` from another definition. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, the global loaders are convenient for a script or standalone app, especially on Windows since most DLL basenames work as a Python identifier because Windows automatically adds the ".DLL" to the name. If the name isn't a valid identifier, then you have to use subscript syntax such as `ctypes.cdll['libc.so.6']`.